# How replace dataSource in soapui?

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

Soapui Pro provides craation data driven tests with DataSource. So you can read file (for example) line by line, extract properties from line and run all tests. So if the file contains 10 line you can run test 10 times with different data. But waht if I do not gave Soapui Pro? Is there any workarounds to create one test case, read dataa from file and run same test case test several times with out pro version? Is that possible with adding groovy test step to soapui? (sorry I do not know groovy).

**NOTE**. The question about creating test in soapui, not about reading soapui xml project file with java and run all test from java.

Answer (score 0):

The algorith is :

1. write before and teardown scripts in testcase
2. Add groovy script as last test step.
3. Move test execution to the first test step by groovy.

More details you can get [this](http://testautomationnoob.blogspot.ru/2012/10/soapui-data-looping-with-groovy-script.html)

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this..check out http://www.doan.me/script-library-in-soapui-free.aspx
I am currently using this to read data and do other manipulations